# Nagios on a virtual network

Tags: linux, linux-networking, nagios, bgp, ospf

I am trying to emulate a virtual network in Kathara (ex. NetKit), based on OSPF and BGP routing and I am new to this. After emulating the network I need to monitor it using Nagios, but my question is how is it possible? My virtual network is running on an Ubuntu distro, do I need another virtual machine where I should install Nagios, or how does it work exactly? I am new to these technologies and I don't really understand what point I am missing. From what I know Nagios should be installed on a server and the NRPE on the monitored one..but in this situation I just cannot see clearly.

Thank you in advance and excuse me if any mistakes have been made.

Answer (score 0):

There is more than one way to do it.

If your Ubuntu box can reach your virtual network then you could install Nagios directly in Ubuntu.  https://linuxhint.com/install_nagios_ubuntu/

But you could also create a container for it.  This might be cleaner and easier to rebuild if you're recreating your emulation to try different things.  https://hub.docker.com/r/manios/nagios is one way to go, but there are a variety of container builds for nagios available.

Either way - the key prerequisite for it working is that wherever you install nagios needs to see your virtual network.